# mac terminal g++ file.cpp -o file.exe; file.exe unable to run on windows

Tags: c++, cross-compiling

When I try to directly run the exe file in windows 7 x64 the system pushed the error message "Incompatible check system information". Both my mac and window7 are x64, so what should I do ?

Comment: OSX and Windows are two different systems, they are not compatible, you can't build a program for one system and expect it to run on another. If you want to build for another system (different *target* and *host* systems) you should read about *cross compilation*.

Comment: Recompile the code in Windows with Visual C++ or another compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ELLCC](http://ellcc.org):

```
[~] Richards-Mac-mini% cat main.cpp 
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
[~] Richards-Mac-mini% ~/ellcc/bin/ecc++ -target x86_64-w64-mingw32 -o hello main.cpp
[~] Richards-Mac-mini% file hello
hello: PE32+ executable for MS Windows (console) Mono/.Net assembly
[~] Richards-Mac-mini%
```

There are binary downloads available for several Linux systems as well as Windows and Mac OS.